# call hierachy for python profilehooks

Tags: python, performance, profiling

Python's [profilehooks](https://github.com/mgedmin/profilehooks) are really a great way to identify performance bottlenecks. I am using the `@profile` decorator and usually I have an output similar to this:

`ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   14.408   14.408  115.486  115.486 ...
        1    0.000    0.000   75.578   75.578 ...
        2    0.000    0.000   75.578   37.789 ...
        2   74.937   37.469   75.578   37.789 ...
       10    0.000    0.000   23.893    2.389 ...
       10    0.001    0.000   23.893    2.389 ...
       10    0.461    0.046   23.891    2.389 ...
    35969    1.663    0.000   23.440    0.001 ...
   107907    4.825    0.000   18.174    0.000 ...
   252099    5.917    0.000   11.686    0.000 threadsafe.py:42(__call__)
        4    0.000    0.000   11.379    2.845 ...
        4    0.000    0.000   11.366    2.842 ...
   107907    1.203    0.000    8.441    0.000 ...`

It seems as **threadsafe.py:42** is unnecessarily called very often by some code of mine. Now I need to know why it is called that often. In the past I used to set a breakpoint in this function to identify who is calling this method. It turns out to be very time-consuming, because many of those calls are are valid.

Can you share a better way to identify which code is calling another function in python? Maybe a kind of result list ordered by frequency?

Thank you!

Comment: [*Try this.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771) It's simple and tells you what you need to know.

Comment: If you want full profiling (to get the complete call hierarchy/frequency), and you're on linux, you can try [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/Profiling)